# How to turn off in-app purchases in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying run my iOS app on my device but I get the error Cannot create a iOS App Development provisioning profile for "com....".
Your development team, "____", does not support the In-App Purchase capability. How do I remove the In-App Purchase capability? My Apple developer program membership expired.

EDIT: Theres no option to turn it off

[image: Image xcodee]

Comment: “My Apple developer program membership expired.” Renew it. You cannot run on a device without one.

Answer (score 0):

To Enable  `In-App Purchase` Option in **xCode**

- Add **Apple-id**/**Account** in **xCode** first (if not added.)

For **On/Off** `In-App Purchase` in **xCode**

> **Project-Target  ->  Capabilites  ->  In-App Purchase (ON/OFF)**

- Image

[image]

Comment: You've to add apple id/account in xcode to  show this option.

Comment: I have added apple id and password....Even In-App Purchase option is not showing.Is there anyother reason?